# ReplayKit - finishBroadcastWithError not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13, replaykit

I have in my application Broadcast Upload extension. In broadcastStarted method I would like to, check does user is logged into my app. I've found how to do it in Apple WWDC presentation, but this resolve not works. Application does not streaming, but status bar showing that App still streaming. Here is my code:

```
override func broadcastStarted(withSetupInfo setupInfo: [String : NSObject]?) {
    let condition = User.isLogged() // THIS IS FALSE 
    if(condition){
        Uploader.startBroadcast(to: "demoChannel1")
    }
    else{
        let userInfo = [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: "Not Logged In"]
        let error = NSError(domain: "RPBroadcastErrorDomain", code: 401, userInfo: userInfo)
        finishBroadcastWithError(error)
        print("User is not logged")
    }
}
```

In console I can see message "User is not logged" but I see in status bar something like this

[image: Screenshot from my iPhone]

I have checked it in iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone 8 (iOS versions 13.4 and 13.3.1)

I will be grateful for any help

Comment: Remove the below method from the sample handler.

    override func finishBroadcastWithError(_ error: Error) {
    }